# How can I replace all types of a nested object recursively based on some conditions?

Tags: typescript, type-mapping

In the [Further Exploration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#further-exploration) example on TypeScript website they show us a way to replace the type of a property with a different type based on some conditions.

How can we do the same but in a recursive way? i.e. not only map the first level properties, but any nested property that passes the check.

The example:

```
type ExtractPII<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: Type[Property] extends { pii: true } ? true : false;
};

type DBFields = {
  id: { format: "incrementing" };
  name: { type: string; pii: true };
};

type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = ExtractPII<DBFields>;
// type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = { id: false; name: true; }
```

What I need:

```
type DBFields = {
  id: { format: "incrementing", foo: { type: string; pii: true } };
  name: { type: string; pii: true };
};

type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = ExtractPII<DBFields>; 
// type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = { id: { format: string; foo: true }; name: true; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `false` case, you just need to execute another check to see if the type is an object, and then call `ExtractPii` on that property.

```
type ExtractPII<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends { pii: true } 
    ? true 
    : T[P] extends object 
      ? ExtractPII<T[P]> 
      : T[P];
};
```

This will results in:

```
type DBFields = {
  id: { format: "incrementing", foo: { type: string; pii: true } };
  name: { type: string; pii: true };
};

type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = ExtractPII<DBFields>;

const a: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = {
    name: true,
    id: {
        foo: true,
        format: "incrementing"
    }
}
```

If you want in the `false` case the value `false`, then just replace `T[P]` with `false`:

```
type ExtractPII<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends { pii: true } 
    ? true 
    : T[P] extends object 
      ? ExtractPII<T[P]> 
      : false;
};
```

Comment: .. but the resulting type is kind of ugly, is there a way to clean it up? see the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAAoEksB4AqAfFALxQDeAUFFANoZQCWAdlANYQgD2AZlPgF0AXP3oCoEBBGYATAM4UoYRoxFIArtAC+UajSgB+KBuh6aI-GIlTZCrgCMAVhHS79+o-CRpMOAmOIzfQsxAG5KLXDKUEgoABEAIQAxRggAG3lSCj1GGRFyKB4uRABbZGARACIWVEQIEulgFgBzSoAaQq4ufONwCBE5JBbQpRU1RE0oHUi9ZmQGnpj+qEHEYdHVYwntcJnovqgAeScXYDkAOQgIGRaAcTiMACU49IgmrlYyLxR0bDxElLpeSEcIAelB+gAegZKJRUB9BlBkCJjs50BcrjdmM17k8Xmk3owPlkqO45gstpo2kFcvkgu4it1KRBqe4GcUyhUoNVmLV6o0WpUgloIpQgA)

Comment: @fusio sorry for the late answer, do you mean the type?

Comment: yes, just wondering if it is possible to have a cleaner type -- but it is not a big deal

i.e. cleaner than 
`type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = {
    id: ExtractPII<{
        format: "incrementing";
        foo: {
            type: string;
            pii: true;
        };
    }>;
    name: true;
}`

Comment: @fusio, sorry but this currently is not possible. This is the preview given by the intellisense, there are a bunch of issues on the typescript repo opens regarding this, but currently there are no options.